# Is Panini avatar of some deity?

Tags: sanskrit, panini

Panini's work on Sanskrit is considered as the basis of the Sanskrit Grammar.

I want to know if Panini is avatar of some deity ?

Comment: Unlike Patañjali, Pāṇini doesn't seem to have a lot of myth around him, apart from the account that he dies due to a lion attacking him in the Pañcatantra, which is not supplemented with any other sources. siṃho vyākaraṇasya kartur aharat prāṇān priyān pāṇineḥ. Other than that, in popular tradition, it is considered Śiva bestowed Pāṇini with knowledge of grammar and alphabet or inspired him.  I have never seen or read him being portrayed in tradition as an avatāra of some deity though. –

Comment: No where is he shown as an avatāra. In all places, he is shown or described either as an ācārya (by Patañjali, Kātyāyana), r̥ṣi (by Bhartr̥hari and others) or a scholar (grammarian, linguist etc. ), as he is seen by modern scholarship. Patañjali on the other hand is considered an avatāra of śeṣa in popular traditions.